# Android Studio HAXM With AMD...?

Tags: android, kernel, haxm

So I'm trying to install **HAXM**, and I've tried everything for 4 days now, still nothing. My question is, do you need an Intel CPU to install **HAXM** because that's the only reason I can think of that it wouldn't work. I have gone into my BIOS and enabled virtualization, and I have a **64-bit AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon Graphics HD** that supports acceleration and virtualization with **8GB's of RAM**...

I remember reading somewhere you either need Intel or AMD. Can anyone help, becasue I'm about to give up on Android Studio 100%.

Also, I can't use my phone for testing either, so I need to use the emulator. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. HAXM currently supports only Intel based processors. Had read somewhere(sorry not able to find the link) that AMD has a virtualization setup just like HAXM for LINUX platforms. You could try GenyMotion emulators for your development purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AMD processor, you can download an ARM image,x86 image need install HAXM which need VT-x support, and only intel's CPU support it.
So download "ARM EABI V7a system image" it works well or try using "genymotion emulator"
Hope this help u!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows,I highly recommend to use [Visual Studio Android emulator.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

It works really fast (I have similar chipset and 6 GB's of RAM), much faster than native emulator by Google, and it's free unlike Genymotion which I used too, especially when it comes to rich feature set. You can use this emulator with Android Studio, first laucn Microsoft emulator and then in AS when you push "Run" button, you'll get a window, where you can see your MS emulator setted up as a running device, click this checkbox and then "OK" button and you're good to go, it's like just a few seconds to laucn your app. BTW, haven't tried out cordova apps, but I think it'll be same great.

Answer (score 1):

Driver available direct from INTEL here - https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager .

From readme:

Hardware Requirements:

- Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

Answer (score 1):

AMD is on Windows supported since July 2018. You have to enable Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX):

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html